# Values not being written to cells, get popup though

Tags: excel, for-loop, if-statement, vba

Need help on below code which is not writing values to the cells but displays the msgbox

```
Sub SPD()
    Dim Col1, col2, col3, i, j, LRow, LCol As Long
    Dim st1, st2, st3 As String
    i = 0
    j = 0
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    st1 = "Salus Hosting"
    LRow = Workbooks("Data").Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LRow
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 10).Value = "Salus Hosting" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 30).Value = "EC2" Then
            MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 10).Value & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 30)
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 10).Value
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 17).Value
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 20).Value
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 21).Value
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 29).Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want the values to be written to the worksheet being added?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values are to be written to the sheet being added, the following change might help.

```
Sub SPD()
Dim Ws as Worksheet     ''(changed)
Dim Col1, col2, col3, i, j, LRow, LCol As Long
Dim st1, st2, st3 As String
i = 0
j = 0
Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add      ''(changed)
st1 = "Salus Hosting"
LRow = Workbooks("Data").Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LRow
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 10).Value = "Salus Hosting" And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 30).Value = "EC2" Then
        MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 10).Value & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 30)
        Ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 10).Value   ''(changed)
        Ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 17).Value   ''(changed)
        Ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 20).Value   ''(changed)
        Ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 21).Value   ''(changed)
        Ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 29).Value   ''(changed)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```